# Scala - Convert map key value pair to string

Tags: scala

I have to convert Map to string with given 2 delimiters and I wanted to use my own delimiter

I have done with the below code

```
Map("ss"-> "yy", "aa"-> "bb").map(data => s"${data._1}:${data._2}").mkString("|")
```

The out out is ss:yy|aa:bb

I'm looking for the better way.

Comment: You could destructure your key-value pairs in the function passed to `map`, for better readability: `map { case (key, value) => s"$key:$value" }`

Comment: Thanks for your comments I'm looking the better answer specially for  s"$key:$value" part

Comment: Define "better"...

Comment: Using any map library function with out string concatenation like .mkString

Comment: By better do you mean "something that looks prettier to me, in my mind?". If so, I don't think we can help much.

Comment: I don't know if it is any better, but alternative approach would be: `myMap.map(x => x.productIterator.mkString(":")).mkString("|")`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe that `mkString` is the right way of concatenating strings with delimiters. You can apply it to the tuples as well for uniformity, using `productIterator`:

```
Map("ss"-> "yy", "aa"-> "bb")
  .map(_.productIterator.mkString(":"))
  .mkString("|")
```

Note, however, that `productIterator` loses type information. In the case of strings that won't cause much harm, but can matter in other situations.

Answer (score 9):

```
Map("ss" -> "yy", "aa" -> "bb").map{case (k, v) => k + ":" + v}.mkString("|")
```